# How to add styles to a dynamically-generated list item in an initially empty list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a simple todo app, in which the todos, with respective dates are to be shown in a list form below the text input area. I have made an empty list for that and keep on appending todos, along with date. But I want that a strike through should occur across a todo(not across the date), on clicking on the todo. My code can list the todos with date but fails in causing strike-through. What should I change in *function struck(ele)* and correspondingly in *function changeText()*?

```
<div class="container">
<h1>
 Your todos
</h1>

<input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Add a new todo and hit enter" onkeydown="store(this)">
<div class="todos">
<ul id="demo"></ul>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var list = document.getElementById('demo');

function store(ele){
    if(event.keyCode==13){
    changeText();
   }
}

function changeText() {
    var data = document.getElementById('todo').value;
    var d = new Date();
    if(data!='')
    {
        var entry = document.createElement('li');
        var dates = document.createElement("div");
        dates.appendChild(document.createTextNode(d.toDateString()));
        dates.className = "myClass";
        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
        entry.onclick=struck(this);
        entry.appendChild((dates));
        list.appendChild(entry);
   }
}

function struck(ele) {
    ele.style = "text-decoration:line-through; list-style-type:none";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you're calling the `onclick` function instead of assigning it as a handler.

Change

```
entry.onclick = struck(this);
```

to

```
entry.onclick = () => struck(entry);
```

Then separate the description into its own element, so it alone can get the strikethrough.

```html
<body>

<div class="container">
<h1>
 Your todos
</h1>

<input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Add a new todo and hit enter" onkeydown="store(this)">
<div class="todos">
<ul id="demo"></ul>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var list = document.getElementById('demo');

function store(ele){
    if(event.keyCode==13){
    changeText();
   }
}

function changeText() {
    var data = document.getElementById('todo').value;
    var d = new Date();
    if(data!='')
    {
        var entry = document.createElement('li');
        entry.description = document.createElement('span');
        entry.appendChild(entry.description);
        entry.description.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ' + d.toDateString()));
        entry.onclick = () => struck(entry);
        list.appendChild(entry);
   }
}

function struck(ele) {
    ele.description.style = "text-decoration:line-through; list-style-type:none";
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: The only problem with this code is that the date is now being printed in the next row, whereas I want it to be printed in the same row as the todo

Comment: In that case, you want to use a `<span>` instead of a `<div>`. I've changed the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that Eric has given works great but if I may suggest a minor change, your `store() function doesn't function on firefox` but it does on chrome, thus I made a few changes of my own to it and you could use it as I find it a better approach towards it.

```
var enterPressed = function(){
    document.getElementById("todo").onkeyup = function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13)
        changeText();
  };
};

enterPressed();
```

instead of

```
function store(ele){
    if(event.keyCode==13){
    changeText();
   }
}
a
and onkeydown in input.
```

```js
var list = document.getElementById('demo');

var enterPressed = function(){
    document.getElementById("todo").onkeyup = function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13)
        changeText();
  };
};

function changeText() {
  var data = document.getElementById('todo').value;
  var d = new Date();
  if (data != '') {
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
        entry.description = document.createElement('span');
        entry.appendChild(entry.description);
       entry.description.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" " + d.toDateString()));
        entry.onclick = () => struck(entry);
        list.appendChild(entry);
  }
}

function struck(ele) {
  ele.description.style = "text-decoration:line-through; list-style-type:none";
}

enterPressed();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    Your todos
  </h1>
  <input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Add a new todo and hit enter">
  <div class="todos">
    <ul id="demo">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The *store()* function was working, however, I had enough trouble initially to get it work. Thanks for pointing out another method!!

Comment: @aQwusjargon No problem :)

Comment: @aQwusjargon Update, your function only works only on chrome, not on firefox.

Comment: I copied your code instead of *function store()* and removed *onkeydown()* part, but now its not accepting on pressing enter!!

Comment: @aQwusjargon It does, you can try it on the snippet as well. You need to add "enterPressed();" at the end of your javascript code.

Comment: okay, my bad, it does work. Yes, I had forgotten the `enterPressed();`. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for guidance ':)

Comment: @aQwusjargon No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $ = function (selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
};

var list = $("#demo");

function store(ele) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    changeText();
  }
}

function dynamicEvent() {
  this.description.style = "text-decoration:line-through; list-style-type:none";
}

function changeText() {
  var data = $("#todo").value;
  var date = new Date();
  
  if (data) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.description = document.createElement('span');
    li.className = 'todo'; // Class name
    li.innerHTML = data; // Text inside
    li.appendChild(li.description);
    li.description.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ' + date.toDateString()));
    li.onclick = dynamicEvent; // Attach the event!
    $('#demo').appendChild(li); // Append it
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>
 Your todos
</h1>

  <input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Add a new todo and hit enter" onkeydown="store(this)">
  <div class="todos">
    <ul id="demo"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it.

```js
var list = document.getElementById('demo');

const items = [];

const item = e => {
  const el = document.createElement('li');
  el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<span class="title">${ e.t }</span><div class="time">${e.d}</div>`);
  const title = el.querySelector('.title');
  const time  = el.querySelector('.time' );
  let strike = 0;
  
  el.addEventListener('click', _ => el.querySelector('span').style.textDecoration = !!(++strike % 2) ? 'line-through' : '');
  
  list.appendChild(el);
  
  return { el, title, time };
};

function store(ele) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    items.push(item({ t: ele.value, d: (new Date()).toDateString() }));
    console.log(items);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    Your todos
  </h1>
  <input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Add a new todo and hit enter" onkeydown="store(this)">
  <div class="todos">
    <ul id="demo"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```